# Confusion related to a derivation

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

I have a confusion related to a derviation

If k is any natural number and k' is largest natural number that is strictly smaller than 7/8k. Then how come

$7/8k - k' >= 1/8$

Answer (score 3):

If $\frac78 k-k'<\frac18$, then $7k-8k'<1$, so $7k-8k'\leq 0$, so $k'\geq \frac78k$, a contradiction.